# Lotus Notes OLEDB/ODBC connection failure with SQL Server 2016

Tags: odbc, lotus-notes, sql-server-2016, lotus-domino, oledbconnection

I am new to Lotus Notes and I am trying to connect to SQL server from lotus notes application. I am able to connect to SQL server 2012 version but unable to connect to SQL server 2016 version. I have upgraded my OLEDB version to 18 and also OBDC version to 17 and I am using TLS 1.2. I am getting **SSL security error**. Can someone please suggest how can I make a connection to SQL server 2016 using OLEDB or ODBC connection. Also I have tried the below code:

```
With con
        .Provider = "SQLOLEDB" 
        .Server = "SQLServerName"
        .Database = "DatabaseName" 
        .Metadata = "tbl_CURRENCY"
    End With
```

But the above code was not helpful. Can someone please tell me what should be the provider value if I am using ODBC connection.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The `SQLOLEDB` provider is the legacy one. Try specifying `MSOLEDBSQL.1` to use the newer OLE DB provider. I don't know anything about Lotus Notes but, since the `SQLOLEDB` provider works with the older SQL Server version, it's probably using ADO so it's better to use OLE DB instead of ODBC.

Comment: Yes we are using it.
Thanks